# Create numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

```
[[6, '22:20:22'], [0, '22:21:54'], [1, '22:25:07'], [2, '06:26:25'], [3, '06:17:34'], [4, '10:39:53'], [6, '10:40:09']]
```

in this array, the first value is an index and the second value is time.

I want to count given time interval how many index are present in this array and plot like this.

```
[[50 49 28 71 65 50  7]
 [26 40 61 48 22 14 63]
 [95 85 52  7 36 80 70]
 [20 38  4 16 98 56 14]
 [15 88 14 10  4 84 52]
 [75 53 93 67 44 90 91]
 [ 2 60 66 23 28 53 18]
 [59 65 68 36 81 24 89]
 [76 34 85 56 63 73 36]
 [41  6 17 31  6 50 16]
 [30 28 75 32 89 38 29]
 [ 2 83 76 18 64 41 22]]
```

in this array, each row represent 0 to 6 and each row represent 00:00:00 to 22:00:00
like this

```
              0  1  2  3   4  5  6

00:00:00    [[50 49 28 71 65 50  7]
02:00:00     [26 40 61 48 22 14 63]
04:00:00     [95 85 52  7 36 80 70]
06:00:00     [20 38  4 16 98 56 14]
08:00:00     [15 88 14 10  4 84 52]
10:00:00     [75 53 93 67 44 90 91]
12:00:00     [ 2 60 66 23 28 53 18]
14:00:00     [59 65 68 36 81 24 89]
16:00:00     [76 34 85 56 63 73 36]
18:00:00     [41  6 17 31  6 50 16]
20:00:00     [30 28 75 32 89 38 29]
22:00:00     [ 2 83 76 18 64 41 22]]
```

each value inside the array represents the count of each index in that time period.
How can I achieved this

Comment: This isn't quite clear. Will you please elaborate a bit more on the algorithm?

Comment: Hello brother, I have a large dataset it represents the above array. I want to get each time interval how many indexes are represented as an bellow array

Comment: What is the grid of numbers? Is it data you have elsewhere, or is it supposed to be generated from the list of numbers and times at the top of the question?

Comment: grid number is a count of the index of given time interval.

Comment: in the bottom of the table, it represents it like 24:00:00 to 00:00:00, 0 the index count is 50

Comment: 00:00:00 to 02:00:00, 5 the index count is 14

Answer (score 0):

Your array (labeled as `x`) can be converted into a dataframe directly

```
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
```

Then you may use `pd.to_timedelta` to convert time into timedelta which allows you to use `dt.round` to round the timedelta to "every-two-hours"

```
df[1] = pd.to_datetime(df[1]).dt.round('2h').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Finally this will give you the table.

```
df.value_counts().unstack().transpose()
```